# Is there a way to use conditional predicate on a Java stream?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, predicate

I use Java 8, I have a list of String and I want to extract the string which matches (or not) a regex:

```
switch (condition) {
    case "A":
         return myListOfString.stream().filter(myString -> myString.matches(myRegex)).findFirst();
    case "B":
         return myListOfString.stream().filter(myString -> !myString.matches(myRegex)).findFirst();
}
```

It's exactly the same code in the two cases, except for the `!` “NOT”. I want to extract the string which matches the regex or the string which does not match the regex, according to a condition. I'm sure it's possible to do this in the same stream with a Predicate but I don't find how.

Is there a way to do this without duplicating code in only one stream?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: what do you think will happen if your list does not have an element that matches the regex, and you call `findFirst`? This question is vague, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)

Comment: @Eugene `findFirst` returns an `Optional`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I was sure I saw a `get` call there :| nvm...

Comment: @Eugene I have not copied all my code to focus on my problem :)

Comment: there is `Pattern::asPredicate`that might help you here

Comment: You're using a switch, but treating it as if. `Predicate p = myString -> myString.matches(myRegex);` Then test your condition. `if( caseB ){ p = Predicate.not(p);}` Then stream/filter return. You wouldn't have any duplication.

Comment: @matt thanks, I will try with Predicate.negate because Predicate.no was not implemented in Java 8, but it seems to be the same thing.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I didn't know partitioningBy before.
In my case it should be only 2 strings in my list, one which matches the regex and other  one which doesn't match it, so maybe "too much" but very interesting option :)

Comment: @Nono good call, negate is probably more appropriate anyways. I forgot to check java 8 only.

Comment: @Nono "_I didn't know partitioningBy before_" You do know that there's a thing called Javadoc, right?

Comment: Nooo, I didn't know Javadoc before, thanks @AbhijitSarkar :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, before the question gets closed, the answer is to pass a define a predicate to use.

```
Predicate<String> predicate;
switch (condition) {
    case "A":
        predicate = myString -> myString.matches(myRegex);
    case "B":
        predicate = myString -> !myString.matches(myRegex);
}

return myListOfString.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst();
```

Note, I didn't try to compile, but it should get you the gist.

Comment: Or in recent version of Java, one can use a [switch expression](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361)

Comment: Just keeping it simple.

Comment: You'd need a default since predicate may not have been initialized.

Comment: As of Java 11, use [`Predicate.not`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)): `condition.equals( "A" ) ? predicate : Predicate.not( predicate )`

Comment: There’s no sense in using `filter(predicate::test)` instead of just `filter(predicate)`. And `switch` needs a `default`, otherwise you get an error, “`predicate` might not have been initialized”

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then you want to use the same stream unter different conditions?

Just move the switch-case into the filter.

```
return myListOfString.stream().filter(myString -> {

switch (condition) {
    case "A":
         return myString.matches(myRegex);
    case "B":
         return !myString.matches(myRegex));
    default: 
         return false;
    }
}

}).findFirst();
```

Or create a predicate for the filter.

```
var myPredicate = (myString) -> {
switch (condition) {
    case "A":
         return myString.matches(myRegex);
    case "B":
         return !myString.matches(myRegex));
    default: 
         return false;
    }
};

return myListOfString.stream().filter(myPredicate).findFirst();
```

Comment: You pass `filter(myPredicate)` as it already is a predicate.

Comment: You can not use `var` with a lambda expression like `var myPredicate = (myString) -> {…`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Separate your inputs into two lists, those that passed your predicate test, and those that flunked the test. Collect those lists in a `Map< Boolean , List< String > >`.

```
List
.of( "dog" , "giraffe" , "cockatiel" , "cat" )
.stream()
.collect( 
    Collectors
    .partitioningBy( 
        word -> word.length() <= 3   // `Predicate` test. Looking for short words versus long words.
    ) 
)                                    // Returns a `Map< Boolean , List< String > >`.
.get(
    Boolean.TRUE
)                                    // Returns one of the two `List` objects contained in our map.
.toString()
```

> [dog, cat]

## `Collectors.partitioningBy`

As [commented by Abhijit Sarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864586/is-there-a-way-to-use-conditional-predicate-on-a-java-stream#comment121704186_68864586), you could use a specialized [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) to create a map with two keys for each possible `Boolean`, and values are each a list of the inputs that matched or did not match your predicate. See [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)).

Out predicate is testing for short words, those with three or less characters: `word -> word.length() <= 3`.

We produce two lists. The short words (those that met our predicate test) are in a list assigned to the `Boolean.TRUE` key. The long words (those that failed our predicate test) are in a list assigned to `Boolean.FALSE`.

```java
List< String > words = List.of( "dog" , "giraffe" , "cockatiel" , "cat" ) ;
Map< Boolean , List< String > > map = words.stream().collect( Collectors.partitioningBy( word -> word.length() <= 3 ) ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "map = " + map ) ;
System.out.println( "short words = " + map.get( Boolean.TRUE ) ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/S6huFc).

> map = {false=[giraffe, cockatiel], true=[dog, cat]}
>
> short words = [dog, cat]

Comment: Quiet heavy when all the OP wants to do, is `findFirst()`…